# it is possible to create conference by application endpoint in ucma 5

Tags: ucma

it is possible to create conference by **application endpoint** in ucma 5 (not by user endpoint)?
this is my code :

```
ServerPlatformSettings serverPlatformSettings = new ServerPlatformSettings(_applicationName, _applicationHostFQDN, _applicationPort, _applicationGruu);
_serverCollabPlatform = new CollaborationPlatform(serverPlatformSettings);
_platformStartupCompleted.WaitOne();


ApplicationEndpointSettings appEndpointSettings = new ApplicationEndpointSettings(_applicationContactURI, _serverFqdn, 5061);
_applicationEndpoint = new ApplicationEndpoint(_serverCollabPlatform, appEndpointSettings);
_endpointInitCompletedEvent.Reset();
_endpointInitCompletedEvent.WaitOne();


ConferenceScheduleInformation conferenceScheduleInformation = new ConferenceScheduleInformation();
onferenceScheduleInformation.AccessLevel = ConferenceAccessLevel.Invited;
conferenceScheduleInformation.Description = "Conference Test";conferenceScheduleInformation.ExpiryTime = System.DateTime.Now.AddHours(5);
conferenceScheduleInformation.LobbyBypass = LobbyBypass.EnabledForGatewayParticipants;
conferenceScheduleInformation.AutomaticLeaderAssignment = AutomaticLeaderAssignment.Everyone;
ConferenceMcuInformation audioVideoMCU = new ConferenceMcuInformation(McuType.InstantMessaging);
conferenceScheduleInformation.Mcus.Add(audioVideoMCU);
_gatewayEndpoint.ConferenceServices.BeginScheduleConference(conferenceScheduleInformation, 
EndScheduleConference, _gatewayEndpoint.ConferenceServices);
_waitForConferenceScheduling.WaitOne();
```

but when execute this code , i see this error :

"The operation is invalid on an ApplicationEndpoint when a proxy has not been specified or the CollaborationPlatform does not use Mutual Tls."

and i set certificate for serverPlatformSettings

```
ServerPlatformSettings serverPlatformSettings = new ServerPlatformSettings(_applicationName, _applicationHostFQDN, _applicationPort, _applicationGruu, certToUse);
```

but when execute new code , i see these errors :

- by one certificate  : i see this error

  A 404 (Not Found) response was received from the network and the operation       failed

  - by another certificate  : i see this error:

  The data session subscription to server failed. ---> Mic rosoft.Rtc.Signaling.TlsFailureException: Unknown error (0x80131500) ---> Micros
  oft.Rtc.Internal.Sip.RemoteDisconnectedException: Peer disconnected while outbou
  nd capabilities negotiation was in progress ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketExcept
  ion: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Comment: You need to set CollaborationPlatform object with Tls header to supply tls to your platform. If Lync server doesn't have TLS, you need to specify that before launching your platform.

Comment: Make sure you follow the instructions here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn466115(v=office.16).aspx#Anchor_2
This should get you a "correct" certificate for the pool setup you have.